# Why wont this div direct me to the site?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way I can get the NW div to click to google?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%
}

#NW {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: orange
}

#NE {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: blue
}

#SW {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: green
}

#SE {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">
  <div id="NW"></div>
</a>

<a href="https://www.google.com">
  <div id="NE"></div>
</a>

<a href="https://www.google.com">
  <div id="SE"></div>
</a>

<a href="https://www.google.com">
  <div id="SW"></div>
</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: it should open the link you've specified i.e google.com. Do you mean to open in a separate tab?

Comment: All four of your sections will correctly navigate to Google as it stands.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm afraid to say it actually is OK since HTML5 was released 13 years ago!

Comment: Correct; I've updated that comment. I forgot `<a>` has a transparent content model temporarily, and thought it only allowed phrasing content...

Comment: @ObsidianAge My bad I just realized that its not working in ClickFunnels (a website builder)

Answer (score 1):

On my systems (Safari on IOS 14; Edge, Chrome, Firefox, IE11 on Windows10) clicking on a rectangle takes me to the google site if I run the code direct.

If I run it through the the Stackoverflow snippet system though it does not, and that is because the snippet system uses an iframe to run the user's code and google doesn't allow itself to be run in an iframe.

It may be useful to have details of the system and browser and any other contextual stuff (like how is the code embedded in other code?) which may cause it not to function in your system.

Meanwhile it could be worth trying to swap the positioning of the anchor element by making that have the fixed position, top, left and dimensions of its child div so that it is forced to take up non-null space itself and see if that removes the problem.